# Utilizar mysql_fetch_assoc mais de uma vez

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estou com uma grande duvida quanto ao mysql_fetch_assoc em while.
o que acontece é o seguinte, tenho uma página onde eu faço uma busca em banco de dados e retorno para um while as informações existentes com mysql_fetch_assoc, o problema é, quando quero fazer este while duas vezes, ele simplesmente anula, então estou fazendo duas buscas no banco de dados na mesma página, só mudando uma situação por causa do primeiro mysql_fetch_assoc que anula o segundo e por ai vai. o código atua é este.

```
$buscar_conteudotag = mysql_query('SELECT msg_message FROM flq_message WHERE msg_private LIKE 0 ORDER BY msg_id DESC') or die (mysql_error());
while($quantidade_de_tag = mysql_fetch_assoc($buscar_conteudotag)) {}

$buscar_conteudoclosest = mysql_query("SELECT msg_message FROM flq_message WHERE msg_private LIKE 0 AND msg_message LIKE '%".$closest."%' OR '%".$closest."%' ORDER BY msg_id DESC") or die (mysql_error());
while($buscar_conteudolinhaclosest = mysql_fetch_assoc($buscar_conteudoclosest)){}

$buscar_conteudotag = mysql_query("SELECT msg_message FROM flq_message WHERE msg_private LIKE 0 AND msg_message LIKE '%".trim(substr($siteuri, 1))."%' OR '%".trim(substr($siteuri, 1))."%' ORDER BY msg_id DESC") or die (mysql_error());
while($quantidade_de_tag = mysql_fetch_assoc($buscar_conteudotag)) {}
```

o que eu procuro no caso, é uma forma de realizar somente um SELECT para todos os três whiles.
isso existe? se alguém puder me ajudar neste fator.

Comment: Uma dica: as funções `mysql_` são obsoletas. Procure utilizar [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php).

Comment: @Lucas entendo, mas estou aprendendo ainda, não procurei muito sobre o sqli, mas funciona em qualquer servidor linux que rode o slq normal?

Comment: Segundo o manual, deve ter MySQL >= 4.1.13 e PHP >= 5.0.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O que acontece é que o `mysql_fetch_assoc` "consome" as linhas, como diz no manual do PHP: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

> Retorna uma matriz associativa que corresponde a linha obtida **e move o
>   ponteiro interno dos dados adiante.**

O que você pode fazer é salvar o resultado num array...

```
$conteudotag = array();
$buscar_conteudotag = mysql_query('SELECT msg_message FROM ...') or die (mysql_error());
while ($quantidade_de_tag = mysql_fetch_assoc($buscar_conteudotag)) {
    $conteudotag[] = quantidade_de_tag;
}
```

...e depois usá-lo onde for preciso.

Comment: no caso eu só faço isso uma vez na página, e quando eu for utilizar outro while do mesmo conteúdo eu coloco o $conteudotag[]; no lugar do assoc?

Comment: você pode usar `foreach` para iterar o array

Answer (score 3):

Pelo que você diz na descrição, parece que a primeira busca já lhe dá todos os resultados de que você precisa, e o seu único problema é o fato do mysql_fetch_assoc ir mudando o ponteiro interno até o final dos dados durante o while.

Se for isso mesmo, existe a possibilidade de mover o ponteiro de volta para a primeira linha do resultado utilizando o mysql_data_seek antes de fazer o while seguinte, por exemplo:

```
mysql_data_seek($buscar_conteudotag, 0)
```

Comment: no caso eu quero poder utilizar o while com os mesmos resultados muitas veses, mas o assoc não me permite fazer isso, então basta eu inserir o seek antes de outro assoc?

Comment: Não, antes de outro while. Você tentou?